# What gap from water heater to ceiling?

Tags: bathroom, water-heater

I am mounting a new large (150L) water heater inside a bathroom. What gap should there be between the top of the device and the ceiling? Some concerns:

- heat retention instead of being transferred to the neighbours above
- an unenclosed shower(-head) is located 1.3m away; so the lower the heater, the more water spray
- space underneath.

My current bet is 0.2m from appliance to ceiling.

Comment: glass (enamel on steel)  or copper tank?

Comment: Voting to close. Model is not listed and OP is apparently permanently absent.

Answer (score 3):

There should be minimum clearance specifications in the installation manual, so you should consult that. Anything else mentioned here is speculation.

You should shield the water heater from the shower spray.

Comment: Enough clearance so that you can get the sacrificial anode out as well would be good.

Comment: it may not need shielding: some water heaters are installed outdoors and do not need addtional protection from the weather.

Answer (score 0):

If the heater has a anode, you should make enough room above ir that it can be replaced.

Flexiblwe anodes are available. They tapically need about one third the height of the tank for fitment. The solud anhode that comes the the tank can be bent to remove it when it's time to replace it.

If there is unused space above the tank possinbly a hole can be cut in the ceiling to facilitate anode replacement.